# How to install CentOS7 in PRIMERGY TX1310 M1 which already has VMware ESXi 6.5 server in it?

Tags: centos7, vmware, esxi

I have a FUJITSU PRIMERGY TX1310 M1 with VMware ESXi 6.5 server running.
How do I uninstall this and then install CentOS7 to this machine?

I am new to building servers and would be happy if somebody could help me out on this.

Warm regards,
sunnyday

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start the physical system and point it to either a CD-ROM and/or ISO which contains CentOS7. Once booting from the CD-ROM or ISO, it will walk you through the installation process.